# Use of lock and acquire in Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex

I am trying to make a program that simulates a thread race in a maze (represented as a bidimensional array). In each of these boxes there can only be one player, so when I move I must block the positions to which I can move, move and unlock the positions. My first question is the difference between mutex.lock and mutex.acquire. The second, using these locking methods, when one thread has locked and entered the critical phase, can another thread lock other positions if they do not interfere with the other thread? or until the first thread does not finish the others are blocked?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: You should write some toy examples for yourself that test/prove/unprove/answer the questions you are asking. Then play around with those toy examples.